# MySQL: JOIN two tables with matching row names

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables like so:

`user_users`

```
ID    UserGroup    Email
1     3            first@domain.com
2     3            second@domain.com
```

`user_groups`

```
ID    GroupName
2     Some Group
3     Another Group
```

I am retrieving data from both tables in one query, like so:

`SELECT u.*, g.GroupName FROM user_users u JOIN user_groups g ON u.UserGroup = g.ID`

The problem that I'm having is that I need to retrieve all the columns in both tables, but both the `user_users` table and the `user_groups` table have a column name of `ID`.

So, this:

`SELECT u.*, g.* FROM user_users u JOIN user_groups g ON u.UserGroup = g.ID`

... will not return the `ID` from the `user_groups` table.

How can I modify this query so that all the columns in the `user_groups` table can be returned as one array? Where the results will be like:

```
[
    'ID' => 2,
    'UserGroup' => 3,
    'Email' => 'second@domain.com',
    'GroupTable' => [
        'ID' => 3,
        'GroupName' => 'Another Group'
    ]
]
```

Comment: Mysql does return both id columns. It is the php code that does not handle this scenario - known issue for some of the ORMs. You should not use select * in production code anyway to save a bit of typing. Use aliases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to specify each field and put field aliases for ID fields:

```
SELECT u.ID as ‘User ID’, u.UserGroup, u.Email, g.ID as ‘Group ID’  g.GroupName FROM user_users u JOIN user_groups g ON u.UserGroup = g.ID
```

Or try specifying only the ID fields, like this:

```
SELECT u.ID as ‘User ID’, u.*, g.ID as ‘Group ID’, g.* FROM user_users u JOIN user_groups g ON u.UserGroup = g.ID
```

Comment: Thank you, I thought about that, but there are quite a few more columns than are shown in the example so I am trying to do this without having to specify every one.

Comment: The added solution is a really bad idea! It will retrieve the id columns twice. Just to save a bit of typing...

Answer (score 1):

You should try this and to get it in array structure please modify the same through code:

```
SELECT 
  ux.*, 
  uy.* 
FROM 
  user_groups uy 
  JOIN (
    SELECT 
      u1.* 
    FROM 
      user_users u1 
      LEFT JOIN user_users u2 ON (
        u1.UserGroup = u2.UserGroup 
        AND u1.id < u2.id
      ) 
    WHERE 
      u2.id IS NULL
  ) ux ON ux.UserGroup = uy.ID;
```

Comment: Hi, I am new user, could you please assist me to format the same.

Comment: As i want to write 
down vote

please try this and to get it in array structure please modify the same through code

SELECT ux.*, uy.* FROM user_groups

Answer (score 0):

//Hi this might helpfull to you.

```
$sqlQuery = 'SELECT * FROM user_groups';

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sqlQuery);
$stmt->execute();
$output = $stmt->fetchAll();

$sqlUGQuery = 'SELECT * FROM user_users WHERE UserGroup=:userGroupId';
$stmtUG = $conn->prepare($sqlUGQuery);
foreach ($output as $key => &$value) {
    $stmtUG->execute([':userGroupId'=>$value['id']]);
    $value['GroupTable'] = $stmtUG->fetchAll();
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($output);
echo "</pre>";
exit;
```

Output will be as below.
[image]